# Real time optimization of sensor data to reduce log file size by omiting entries

Tags: c#, algorithm, csv, optimization

Updated several times to better describe the current implementation and its usage which was lacking.

**What I want to do:**
I would like to log real time sensor(s) data (voltage) to a log file (CSV) in a size efficient manner (least number of rows). 
Each row must contain all the sensor data at a specific timestamp. This should allow easy graphing, with X-axis being time.

Currently a new row is added every second with all the sensor data.

A typical problem is that the sensor data does not change for days (similar voltage) but then suddenly changes (large voltage change) every few seconds for a short period of time.

In this case I would like to optimize the log file to only include few points when the data is not changing much, but still capture the period of fast changes.

For example, in the following set of data and I only want a new point when the data changes by more than 10.

```
+-----------------------------+
|  Time(sec) Value1   Value2  |
+-----------------------------+
| 1           0        0      |
| 2           5        3      |
| 3           0        1      |
| ...thousand entries...      |
| 1001        15       1      |
| 1002        12       4      |
| 1003        2        1      |
| 1004        3        2      |
|         ...............     |
+-----------------------------+
```

Ideally the output would be:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  Time(sec) Value1   Value2  |
+-----------------------------+
| 1           0        0      |
| 1000        5        3      | <<last value? Mean? extrapolation?
| 1001        15       1      |
| 1002        12       4      | <<last value? Mean? extrapolation?
| 1003        2        1      |
|         ...............     |
+-----------------------------+
```

The algorithm must handle large sudden value changes with out the resultant looking like a gradual increase, this would happen if in the above example only points 1,1001,1003  where included in the output. 
It would look like a pyramid rather than a step change!

They are also details such as in the above output example, point 1000, should it be the last point before the step change, or a mean value between all the points from 1-1000?

Ideally an algorithm exist where the optimized output represents the input waveform as accurately as possible.

**Current Implementation**

Currently all the sensor data is saved once a second to a CSV file. It is then used by non-technical people to view the the trend inside excel or similar by plotting a graph.

The files generated are often very large.

**Research**

I had a look at [Online Linear Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/efficient-online-linear-regression) but I dont think what I want to achieve is curve fitting.

Essentially I dont know what keyword to search for to describe this problem. I have tried the following:

- "how to optimize data captured in a csv file"
- "real time data optimisation by data change algorithm"
- "real time data optimisation by point removal"

Run-length encoding or other encoding pattern compression would no longer allow the user to open the output file for easy graphing. It would first have to be decoded.

["Online Algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) Is the name for the general class of algorithms which process input in a serial fashion

**Questions:**

The resulting CSV file must still be human readable and easily graph-able in excel or similar. This rules out compression or encoding the number of entries in the CSV file.

1. Is their a name for this class of problems /  algorithm?
2. Any commonly used algorithms? (I am programming in C#)

**Update 1**

An alternative description of what i am looking to happen:

1. A new measurement is taken once a second
2. The algorithm receives each measurement at a time
3. The algorithm output must select/generate the smallest number of points which would represent the original waveform if each point where connected by a line.
4. The algorithm must generate this output "online". It does not have the complete dataset.

This description better captures that the output must be a set of points representing the original waveform.

The output must look like the input waveform once graphed in excel or similar. These tools generally just linearly connect the dots.

Here are two example of what the algorithm should be doing. The input data is simplified to be represented with many less points. (Note: Y scales are not identical between examples, the optimization strength would be user controllable)

[image: Example optimized sine wave input]
[image: Example optimized step response]

**Update 2**
Looks like what I am looking may be related to:
"Online piecewise linear interpolation"

I have found "piecewise linear interpolation" trying to see if they work for streaming data.

**Update 3**
"piecewise linear interpolation" is not quite the right algorithm either. This would linearly interpolate between existing points, while i want to generate a new set of points to represent the original data..

Maybe keep monitor the incoming data since the last knot and once all the data  can no longer be represented by a line, insert a new knot and restart? Obvious issue is how to optimally choose where to put the knot..

**Final Update**
Added my own answer below. Algorithms called "Line Simplification algorithms" or "downsampling"/ "data compression" algorithms. The "downsampling"/ "data compression" appears better geared to streaming data.

Will most likely use the "Fan" data compression Algorithms for my problem.

Comment: Perhaps not entirely matching your use case with csv files, but the first thing to google that springs to mind is run length encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) - this might suggest a few ideas to you, especially if using csv files something you can change.

Comment: You can only remove an entry if it "lies of the line formed between the previous and next point". The data in your question cannot be optimized any further. If you add a point at 3h between 1 and 2, also at 0V, then that could be optimized away.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen, I have improved the example description. My entries 1,2,3 are already optimized, but how to tell the algorithm to generate that output if he gets a new data every second?

Comment: The code cannot output point X until point X+1 has arrived, you say "csv file", are you really building a complete csv file every second?

Comment: the software keeps appending a row to the CSV file. Currently it appends a row every second.

Comment: Why don't you just remove points X_i where X_{i-1} = X_i = X_{i+1}?

Comment: Juan, just removing points that are similar to the last point will cause the problem described where the output looks nothing like the input waveform. Using my example data your solution would output only points 1,1001,1003, the resulting graph loops like a piramid and not a step pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm category could be "Line Simplification algorithms" or "downsampling"/ "data compression" algorithms:

**Line Simplification algorithms**

An example would be the ["Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm" /  "iterative end-point fit algorithm" and "split-and-merge algorithm".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

A C# implemententation:[A-Csharp-Implementation-of-Douglas-Peucker-Line-Ap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18936/A-Csharp-Implementation-of-Douglas-Peucker-Line-Ap).

Some can be used for streaming data, such as [Streaming Algorithms for Line Simplification.](http://www.win.tue.nl/~phachenb/Publications/streamingAlgLineSimplification.pdf)

History of research here: [Curve Simplification Turk](http://web.cs.sunyit.edu/~poissad/projects/Curve/about_project.php)

**Downsampling/ "data compression" algorithms**

Question already answered here: [downsampling-excessively-sampled-curves](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50729/downsampling-excessively-sampled-curves)

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little animation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm if you are interested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621

Answer (score 1):

If the voltage doesn't change *at all* for long periods, all you need is [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), which can be trivially done on the fly by comparing the value you are about to save with the last value you saved.

If you want to ignore voltage changes that are less than some small specified amount, then you can simply change the above equality comparison to a test of the magnitude of the difference: is `|curValue - lastWrittenValue| > threshold`? -- and use RLE as before.

Comment: I will edit the original question to add that the CSV (excel) compatibility needs to be kept. All the optimization relying de duplicating "patterns" wont work I think.

Comment: I don't understand how that makes a difference...?

Comment: The RLE algorithm would have to replace all the duplication with some form of compressed description of it. How do i do that in a csv?  I could simply have one entry at time0, then the same entry just before the data changes fast?

Comment: I still don't really understand, I'm afraid.  You can record anything you want in a CSV file.  It sounds to me like you could be using a 2-column format, "Voltage" and "Repeat count" being your columns (or you could use "Time offset" instead of "Repeat count" -- this will just be the running total of "Repeat count").  You don't "replace" anything -- I'm suggesting a way of encoding the information of the file *as you receive* the measurements.

Comment: Ok i understand your idea. It would break the current usage scenario which allows people to look at the trend in excel. By encoding the data they would then need to decode it before graphing. I updated my original question. Sorry for the ommision.

Comment: In your new example, you're using a "Time offset" column just as I suggested.  It's just the running total of the repeat count -- is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a common name for this. You can save this in the following format

```
+------------------------+
|   from   to   value    |
+------------------------+
| time1  time 2  123.345 |
| time2  time 3  13.5    |
| time4  time 5  128.2   |
+------------------------+
```

Save the value only when it deviates significantly from the previous value. The algorithm:

- Loop
- Remember: start_time, start_value
- Get current_value and compare against start_value

  - No difference => keep going
  - Significantly different => write to csv (start_time, end_time, start_value)

Comment: To meet the requirement of the CSV file being graphable i could re-organise your suggestion and have one row per time. BUT they are details which are not covered. e.g if time1-time2  value fluctuates between 123 and 125,, do i extrapolate a middle point? Updated question to better describe issue

Answer (score 0):

Something very simple you could do is to use a **windowed** running average and standard deviation, with a specific window size that spans a modest time period (e.g. 30-40 seconds @ a sampling rate of 1 observation per second) and a specific confidence limit that you want to use to detect deviations (e.g. +/- 2 SD). This will cover a certain period of the most recent observations only, and will allow you to determine if a newly arrived sensor observation deviates from them.

Then, if a newly arrived observation

- Falls outside the confidence limit → log it to your csv & clear the window.
- Falls inside the confidence limit → don't log it to your csv file.

As long as the window is not filled with observations (i.e. it is stabilizing) you also log new observations.

If you combine this with a second avg/sd window that periodically receives the average for the recent period, you can also detect trends over a somewhat larger period.

Note that an added advantage is, that you also have standard deviations available for the voltage observations, if at some point in the future you would like to do more than just monitor individual values.

An implementation of a running average/SD calculator can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269137/2573395. For this problem, I adapted it a bit to also keep track of the time stamps and allow checking if an observation falls in the confidence interval.

```
public class MovingAverageCalculator
{
    public MovingAverageCalculator(int period)
    {
        _period = period;
        _window = new double[period];
        _stamps = new DateTime[period];
    }

    public double Average
    {
        get { return _average; }
    }

    public double StandardDeviation
    {
        get
        {
            var variance = Variance;
            if (variance >= double.Epsilon)
            {
                var sd = Math.Sqrt(variance);
                return double.IsNaN(sd) ? 0.0 : sd;
            }
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    public double Variance
    {
        get
        {
            var n = N;
            return n > 1 ? _variance_sum / (n - 1) : 0.0;
        }
    }

    public bool HasFullPeriod
    {
        get { return _num_added >= _period; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<double> Observations
    {
        get { return _window.Take(N); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> TimeStamps
    {
        get { return _stamps.Take(N); }
    }

    public int N
    {
        get { return Math.Min(_num_added, _period); }
    }

    public int WindowSize
    {
        get { return _window.Length; }
    }

    public bool IsOutOfBounds(double observation, double maxSDDeviation)
    {
        var dev = maxSDDeviation * StandardDeviation;
        return observation < _average - dev || observation > _average + dev;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _num_added = 0;
        _average = 0;
        _variance_sum = 0;
    }

    public void AddObservation(DateTime stamp, double observation)
    {
        // Window is treated as a circular buffer.
        var ndx = _num_added % _period;
        var old = _window[ndx];     // get value to remove from window
        _window[ndx] = observation; // add new observation in its place.
        _stamps[ndx] = stamp;
        _num_added++;

        // Update average and standard deviation using deltas
        var old_avg = _average;
        if (_num_added <= _period)
        {
            var delta = observation - old_avg;
            _average += delta / _num_added;
            _variance_sum += (delta * (observation - _average));
        }
        else // use delta vs removed observation.
        {
            var delta = observation - old;
            _average += delta / _period;
            _variance_sum += (delta * ((observation - _average) + (old - old_avg)));
        }
    }

    private readonly int _period;
    private double[] _window;
    private DateTime[] _stamps;
    private int _num_added;
    private double _average;
    private double _variance_sum;
}
```

The below class provides an example implementation that uses the mentioned strategy using two "chained" moving avg/sd windows.

```
public class VoltageObservationFilter
{
    private readonly MovingAverageCalculator _shortPeriodCalculator;
    private readonly MovingAverageCalculator _longPeriodCalculator;
    private readonly Action<ObservationType, DateTime, double> _onFilteredObservation;
    private readonly double _maxSDDeviation;
    private int _periodCounter;

    public enum ObservationType
    {
        kNewObservation,
        kRecentPeriodAverage,
        kLongPeriodAverage
    };

    public VoltageObservationFilter(
        Action<ObservationType, DateTime, double> onFilteredObservation,
        double maxSDDeviation,
        TimeSpan samplingInterval,
        TimeSpan shortPeriod,
        TimeSpan longPeriod)
    {
        var shortWindowSize = (int)Math.Round(shortPeriod.TotalMilliseconds / samplingInterval.TotalMilliseconds);
        var longWindowSize = (int)Math.Round(longPeriod.TotalMilliseconds / shortPeriod.TotalMilliseconds);
        _shortPeriodCalculator = new MovingAverageCalculator(shortWindowSize);
        _longPeriodCalculator = new MovingAverageCalculator(longWindowSize);
        _onFilteredObservation = onFilteredObservation;
        _maxSDDeviation = maxSDDeviation;
    }

    public void AddObservation(DateTime timeStamp, double voltage)
    {
        if (DoAddObservation(_shortPeriodCalculator, timeStamp, voltage))
        {
            _onFilteredObservation(ObservationType.kNewObservation, timeStamp, voltage);
            _periodCounter = _shortPeriodCalculator.N;
        }
        else if (_periodCounter++ == _shortPeriodCalculator.WindowSize)
        {
            // chaining: add short period average to long period.
            _periodCounter = 0;
            var avgObs = _shortPeriodCalculator.Average;
            var avgTicks = _shortPeriodCalculator.TimeStamps.Average(ts => ts.Ticks);
            var avgStamp = new DateTime((long)Math.Round(avgTicks));
            if (DoAddObservation(_longPeriodCalculator, avgStamp, avgObs))
            {
                _onFilteredObservation(ObservationType.kRecentPeriodAverage, avgStamp, avgObs);
                avgObs = _longPeriodCalculator.Average;
                avgTicks = _longPeriodCalculator.TimeStamps.Average(ts => ts.Ticks);
                avgStamp = new DateTime((long)Math.Round(avgTicks));
                _onFilteredObservation(ObservationType.kLongPeriodAverage, avgStamp, avgObs);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool DoAddObservation(MovingAverageCalculator calculator, DateTime timeStamp, double observation)
    {
        if (!calculator.HasFullPeriod)
        {
            calculator.AddObservation(timeStamp, observation);
            return true; // still stabilizing: log 
        }
        else if (calculator.IsOutOfBounds(observation, _maxSDDeviation))
        {
            calculator.Clear(); // deviation: reset window.
            return true; // requires logging
        }
        else
        {
            calculator.AddObservation(timeStamp, observation);
            return false; // falls within bounds, no logging.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I have not gotten my head around your algorithm yet. How would this handle my step change example? Would i enter the last running average and also the new value outside the window?

Comment: Given that you mentioned that values tend to be pretty stable, It would immediately detect the step change. This will result in (1) reporting that observation (2) clearing the window (3) as a result, also reporting all subsequent observations until the window is filled again and stable. This ensures that whenever there is a deviation, you have at least a window size (30-40 second) period after the deviation logged.

Comment: It is neat that it is sudenly more sensitive after a change. I had not realised this behaviour. The trouble i see (see updated question) is that it would imidiatly pickup the change at time 1001, but then i get two point: (Time 1sec) and (Time 1001sec), if i plot this, the graphing tool would connect these two dots and give the impression of a slow rise rather than a step change.

Comment: For reporting purposes, you could easily cache the last non-logged observation (and its time stamp) and include that when reporting a deviation. Also, what you could do, is to include the average and standard deviation for the entire (30-40 second) period and for the longer (e.g. 30 minutes) period preceding the deviation.

Comment: The output CSV file needs to be used by non technical people to simply graph the data, for each sensor their can only be one value.  Excel will do a linear interpolation between points so whatever my output is, it needs to correctly represent the original signal once graphed. To some extend i need to pre-empt the excel's linear interpolation between points in my dataset.

Comment: Ok, so only include the last non-logged observation when reporting a deviation.