# Calculating a moving average in C# with IronPython Data Stream

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have a sensor that is displaying real-time data through a Python script, running on IronPython.  Unfortunately, IronPython does not support `pandas`, so I am unable to use the `pd.rolling_mean` function in my Python script, or perform much data processing in real-time (as far as I understand).

When I run the below program in Visual Studio, a console application appears, and the data from the sensor starts streaming in.  My goal is to calculate the `rolling_mean` of this data stream, and then to trigger an event once that `rolling_mean` exceeds a certain value.

I am limited to IronPython, because that is what the sensor company requires in order to run their real-time data script.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding ways to process that data stream in real-time.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to write the `rolling_mean` in C# on the data stream that is coming in - similar to the following question: [Calculate a moving std in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265626/calculate-a-moving-standard-deviation).

Thank you for any feedback and support!  My current code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Y to begin:");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();

            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
            paths.Add("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages");
            engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

            try
            {
                py.ExecuteFile("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\Sensor_Data.py");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can embed CPython in .NET with Python.NET http://www.python4.net